# can't activate a sheet

Tags: numpy, python-3.6, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl
import numpy as np

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
hoja1 = wb.get_active_sheet()
hoja1.title = '1'

x = np.linspace(0,100,50)
y = x**2

hoja1.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = 'x'
hoja1.cell(row = 1, column = 2).value = 'y'

for i in range(0, len(x)):
    hoja1.cell(row = i + 2, column = 1).value = x[i]
    hoja1.cell(row = i + 2, column = 2).value = y[i]

wb.save('test_save.xlsx')
```

So this is my code. It Works for saving the data but if I want to create another sheet in the same test_save.xlsx file, what I have to do? I tried this but didn't work out:

```
import openpyxl
import numpy as np

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
hoja1 = wb.get_active_sheet()
hoja2 = wb.get_active_sheet()

hoja1.title = '1'
hoja2.title = '2'

x = np.linspace(0,100,50)
y = x**2

hoja1.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = 'x'
hoja1.cell(row = 1, column = 2).value = 'y'

for i in range(0, len(x)):
    hoja1.cell(row = i + 2, column = 1).value = x[i]
    hoja1.cell(row = i + 2, column = 2).value = y[i]

wb.save('test_save.xlsx')
```

But it doesn't work =(

Comment: Use `wb.create_sheet()`

Comment: Thanks you so much !!! It was very useful